# Django - Cannot assign "'Biography test'": "User.biography" must be a "Biography" instance

Tags: django, model, extend

I have extended the user model with an extra field - biography. It appears in the admin panel as a new section.  Here's a picture:

[image]

Here's the new model:

```
class Biography(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

Here's the profile view:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not request.user == user:
        return render(request, 'no.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user,'products': products})
```

I'm using a form to edit the profile - here's the view:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, initial={'first_name':user.first_name, 'last_name':user.last_name, 'biography':user.biography})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.biography = request.POST['biography']
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user':user, 'products':products})
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)
```

...and here's the form:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    biography = forms.CharField(label='Biography', widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}))
```

Here's a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

I'm mixing something up but I can't figure out what. Doesn't help that I'm new to this ...still trying!

Comment: The problem seems to be with this assignment: `user.biography = request.POST['biography']` . You need to assign a Biography instance; `request.POST['biography']`is a different type.

Comment: Thank you - but - I don't know how to do that.  Do you mean in the view?

Comment: `request.POST['biography']` is a value (string) corresponding to biography key in the dictionary. Try to print it in order to see what and how exactly this is. After that, you will need to create an instance of Biography class with that specific value.

Comment: Not sure I follow - if I use {{user.biography}} in the template it prints "Biography object" to the page - so I create a class for that?

Comment: Did you really create all the code? In your question, you put a class named Biography... So... why are you asking me about a class you already have created? You just have to use it correctly. In your `edit_profile` method, you are assigning a `string` to a `Biography` object (`user.biography`)...

Comment: Ok - no need to be rude - I'm learning as I go along and trying to understand by following tutorials and adapting as I go along.  I know I have a Biography model, I thought you meant in the views.py.  You may fully understand this, some of us don't.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention. But did you understand what I told? How is your User model?

Comment: Yes - I get the premise now - that makes sense.  I'm going to play with that idea this evening.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you have success?

Comment: Eventually, yes.  In the 'edit_profile' view I added `biography.biography` and added `biography.save()` - I changed all entries in the `if form_is_valid` section to use 'form.cleaned.data' also - quite the learning curve since I understood the premise of what you were saying but couldn't visualize it.  Thanks for the clues though.

Comment: Ok, Steve. Glad you had success. I've put an answer with what we discussed in the comments. If you found it helpful, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says:

```
"User.Biography" must be a "Biography" instance.
```

In your `edit_profile` definition, you have the following assignment:

```
user.biography = request.POST['biography']
```

`request.POST['biography']` is not a valid instance of `Biography`. So, you have to create a valid `Biography` instance, according to your `Biography` model, with the `request.POST['biography']`.

After that, you can assign your valid instance to `user.biography`.

I hope it had been useful for you.